# How to use refs with react-native-router-flux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-redux

For 2 simple components, parent, child both using Redux I'm able to use `refs`, to invoke a child method. But how can I achieve same using above library 'react-native-router-flux', where can I set ref to Scenes.

ParentComponent

```
var Parent = new React.createClass({

    render : function() {
        return (<Child ref={(child) => {this.child = child}})
    }

    // able to trigger child.somefunction via this.child.getWrappedInstance().somefunction()


})

module.exports = connect(select)(Parent)
```

ChildComponent

```
var Child = new React.createClass({

    somefunction: function(){
        //working
    }
})

module.exports = connect(select, null, null, {withRef: true})(Child)
```

https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux

render function of Child component after using above library

```
render: function() {
   return (
     <Router>
       <Scene>
         <Scene key="WelcomeModal" component={WelcomeModal} title="welcomeTitle" initial={true} 
             navigationBarStyle={styles.welcomeModal_navigationBarStyle}
             titleStyle={styles.welcomeModal_titleStyle}
             rightTitle='INFO'
             rightButtonStyle={styles.baseModal_rightButtonStyle}
             rightButtonTextStyle={styles.baseModal_rightButtonTextStyle}
             rightButtonIconStyle={styles.baseModal_rightButtonIconStyle}
             ref={(_WelcomeModal) => {this._WelcomeModal = _WelcomeModal}} //need some way to add ref here
         />
       </Scene>
     </Router>
   )
}
```

https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux

Comment: Quick answer is: You can't. What do you need this for? Most uses of `ref` can be solved in other ways.

Comment: To use the react-native-router-flux the flow should be like parent component should only be connected to redux store not child component and it seems the flow is not right, please may i know what is the need of calling child's function in parent class ?

Comment: I have added a PushNotificationController at parent level so its present throughout all the scenes, another way is I add same controller in each and every child component

Comment: Why don't use callbacks?